# Regex URL no numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to only execute a function if the main part of the URL is NOT followed by any numbers. For example, I want the following URL to match:

`http://link.com/groups`

but not

`http://link.com:8001/` or `http://link.com:8000/?alert=true`

I've gotten together the regex `/link.com[^0-9]+/` but it still matches the first part of the links I don't want matched so when I have the statement:

```
   var link = document.URL;
   var re = /link.com[^0-9]+/;
   if (re.exec(link)){
      console.log("hello");
   }
```

"hello" still gets logged out. Is there a way to only execute the function if there are no numbers after the main part of the URL even if part of the URL matches?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: Are you just worried about the port number, or are you worried about parameter names and/or values after the `?` too?

Comment: I don't want any URL that has any numbers after it to get matched

Comment: Use the correct technical terms: "host name", and "port number". Anyway, your regexp is matching because `:` matches `[^0-9]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!...)`

```
/link\.com(?!:\d)/
```

```js
var link = "http://link.com:8000/?alert=true";
var re = /link\.com(?!:\d)/;
if (re.exec(link)) {
  console.log("hello");
} else {
  console.log("no match");  
}
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rH5hK9/2)

Comment: @MarksCode it is allowed to use multiple different regular expressions to solve different parts of the problem.

Comment: @4castle interestingly `http://link.com/groups` doesn't get matched which I thought that expression should have since there the pattern ":\d" does not occur at all after the initial `link.com` bit. Any idea why?

Comment: It does get matched, you just have to get rid of the other sample strings

Comment: @SamuelToh Put the demo in global mode by adding the `g` modifier off to the right [like this](https://regex101.com/r/rH5hK9/3)